# The [mat] tag is only for OpenCV, but other frameworks like MATLAB provide Mat, too

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The mat flag should be used for the class Mat in OpenCV - however, another giant, MATLAB, also provides the MATLAB class. Should mat be used in any case it is a discussion about a programming issue regarding to a matrix?

Should there be a new tag for MATLAB mat?

Here is a link to the fundamental Matlab classes, where Mat gets used as a parent class:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

Comment: There is a [tag:mat-file] tag for the `.mat` file format in MATLAB. There's also a [tag:matrix] tag, and several related tags for sparse matrices and matrix operations. What specifically do we need a new tag for?

Comment: The .mat file is for the .mat file-format not for the Mat datatype (class) in Matlab

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a Mat datatype or class in MATLAB. Do you have a pointer to documentation that states this?

Comment: See edit. However, now that I have read more carefully, I am not quite sure wether it is a good idea or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Should mat be used in any case it is a discussion about a programming issue regarding to a matrix?*

I don't think so. We have [matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix) for this.

> *Should there be a new tag for MATLAB mat?*

I don't think so. As mentioned by [beaker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351840/the-mat-tag-is-only-for-opencv-but-other-frameworks-like-matlab-provide-mat#comment490406_351840), there already exists a tag like [mat-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mat-file) for this exact purpose.

> *Here is a link to the fundamental Matlab classes, where Mat gets used as a parent class:*
>
> https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

In MATLAB, there's no "parent class" for `double`, `logical` etc.
This can be verified by running e.g. `?double` and inspecting the `SuperclassList` in the output:

> Spoiler: it's empty.

```
>> ?double
ans = 
  class with properties:

                     Name: 'double'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0×1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [0×0 meta.package]
     RestrictsSubclassing: 0
             PropertyList: [0×1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [269×1 meta.method]
                EventList: [0×1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0×1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [0×1 meta.class]
```

I would say that the diagram in the page you linked might be misleading for people coming from OOP languages (that have basic `Object`-like classes).